# TypeScript: Can I achieve this use generics and conditional types instead of function overloads?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a function that either:

1. takes a single string as its only argument, in which case it returns a string
2. or takes one string and two numbers as its arguments in which case it returns a number

```
fn('foo') // ✅
fn('foo', 1, 2) // ✅

fn() // type error ❌
fn('foo', 1) // type error ❌
```

I understand that this can be implemented via function overloads in TypeScript

```js
function fn(a: string): string
function fn(a: string, b: number, c: number): number
function fn(a: string, b?: number, c?: number): string | number {
    if(arguments.length === 1) return a
    else return b as number
}

const str = fn('foo') // 'foo'
const num = fn('foo', 1, 2) // 1
```

However, I was wondering if this can also be achieved by **conditional types** without using function overloads since it seems to me that a lot of times conditional types would do the trick.

I guess it is easy to adjust return types according to arguments' types just by using conditional types but it seems impossible to regulate function signatures such has **how many arguments** it can take.

Comment: Why specifically don't you want to use overloads, and why specifically do you want a solution that does use generics and conditional types? Would a solution which doesn't use a conditional type not be acceptable for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
type X = readonly [string, number, number];
type Y = X | [string];

type ReturnVal<T> = T extends X ? number : string;

function fn<T extends Y>(...args: T): ReturnVal<T> {
  if (args.length === 1) return args[0] as ReturnVal<T>;
  else return args[1] as ReturnVal<T>;
}

const val1 = fn("dwe");
const val2 = fn("dwe", 2); //Argument of type '["dwe", 2]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Y'.
const val3 = fn("dwe", 2, 3);
```

I am sure it can be written better but it is just a snippet

Comment: hmmm it seems like all function overloads can be re-written to just conditionals?

Comment: yep, it seems so. You can specify any array instead of `Y` and then use Generics to check. It is the same as JavaScript `if else`, you can use lot of `extends`. But in ide overloads have more explanation to user(at least in webstorm which I am using) if you pass incorrect parameters.

Comment: It is possible to achieve it with conditionals. But you need to use `as` operator and it does not looking very nice.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71117917/11963457 , so I would say it depends on the situation where better use overloads or conditional.  As I know all what you can do with overloads you can do with conditionals but not all what you can do with conditionals can be done with overloads. But conditionals require more code, effort so I would use them for complex things. In simple cases like this, better to use overloads.