# Conditional types don't narrow properly

Tags: typescript

I have a function that either:

1. accepts a string search term, returning a `Promise`
2. accepts a string search term *and* a callback function, returning nothing (`void`)

Here is my implementation:

```js
function fetcher(term: string): Promise<Result[]> {
    return Promise.resolve([{id: 'foo'}, {id: 'bar'}])
}

type Callback = (results: Result[]) => void
function search<T>(term: string, cb?: T ): T extends Callback ?  void : Promise<Result[]> {
    const res = fetcher(term)

    if(cb) {
        res.then(data => cb(data)) // ❌  Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.(2349)
    } 

    return res // ❌ Type 'Promise<Result[]>' is not assignable to type 'T extends Callback ? Promise<Result[]> : void'.
}

const promise = search('key') // ✅ Promise<Result[]>
const v = search('key', () => {})  // ✅ void
```

There are two issues with this:

1. The type of `cb` is still `unknown` after `if(cb)`
2. `return res` cannot match the right type, i.e. `Promise<Result[]>`

How should I properly type such a function?

Comment: Why not use overloads, and dispense with the generic type?

Comment: TS does not support conditional types as a return type. As @jonrsharpe said, you should use overloadings here

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do you mean by dispense with the generic type

Comment: Look at the answer below, you don't need `T extends Callback` so you don't need `T`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yea I know I can use function overloads but I was just wondering if there is a way for it work just using conditionals as well

Comment: Why not use the thing that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually just for you to know:) it is possible to achieve the same thing without overloads using just conditionals even in more than one way.
Just for you to note, here is one way to achieve it:

```
type Result = { id: string };

function fetcher(term: string): Promise<Result[]> {
  return Promise.resolve([{ id: "foo" }, { id: "bar" }]);
}

type Callback = (results: Result[]) => void;

type RetType<T> = [T] extends [Callback] ? void : Promise<Result[]>;
function search<T extends Callback | undefined>(
  term: string,
  cb?: T
): RetType<T> {
  const res = fetcher(term);

  if (cb) {
    res.then((data) => cb(data));
    return undefined as RetType<T>; // need to use as
  }

  return res as RetType<T>;
}

const promise = search("key"); // ✅ Promise<Result[]>
const vjj = search("key", () => undefined); // ✅ void
```

But I would not recommend it as overloads look cleaner.

Comment: just curious for `RetType` why do we have to make `T` a tuple as in `[T]` ? `type RetType<T> = T extends Callback ? void : Promise<Result[]>;` indeed produced a wrong type `const promise: void | Promise<Result[]>` but I couldn't figure out why `[T]` fixed it...

Comment: That is because T could be `never`(because of `cb?: T `). And RetType is distributive type. It is pretty interesting topic, you can check these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926729/why-does-a-typescript-type-conditional-on-t-extends-undefined-with-t-instanti , https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31751

Comment: thanks haha I thought `cb?: T` makes T being `undefined` potentially, didn't know it is `never`