# TypeScript: why is the return type determined by the conditional types doesn't work like the function overload equivalent?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that either accepts one string or two booleans. When it gets a string, it returns a string, when it receives two booleans, it returns a boolean. Here is my implementation using function overloads

```
function foo(a: string): string
function foo(a: boolean, b: boolean): boolean
function foo(a: string | boolean, b?: boolean): string | boolean {
    return a
}
const a = foo(true, true) // boolean
const ad = foo('sf') // string
```

However if I rewrite this to using conditional types

```
function foo2<B extends boolean | undefined,A extends (B extends boolean ? boolean : string)>(a: A, b?: B) : B extends boolean ? boolean : string  {
    return a
}

const aa = foo2(true, true) // boolean
const aa2 = foo2('sdf') // ❌ string | boolean
```

The return type of the string version is off - it says `string | boolean` as opposed to `string`

Not sure what went wrong here. It seems like `B extends boolean ? boolean : string` is not getting the right type for `B` when `b` is not provided.

Comment: hmmm but in this case it seems to me that generic conditional types are checked more _loosely_ since `string | boolean` is a supertype of `string`? how is generic conditional types  more strict than function overloads? but I get it that neither or them is completely safe

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry.  What's happening there is that you are not passing in anything from which `B` can be inferred, so it falls back to the constraint.  See [this example](https://tsplay.dev/N9yDjN) without conditional types at all.  You are perhaps expecting `B` to be `undefined` instead of `boolean | undefined`?  But that's not how type inference and constraints work.

Comment: Perhaps all you need here is a generic parameter default so it falls back to something you want, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMx9zN)?  But then this question has almost nothing to do with conditional types.

Comment: @jcalz could you write up an answer to fix the generic conditional type to so that `foo2('sdf')` will give a correct `string` type if possible? How do I pass  passing in anything from which B can be inferred? Initially `B` is constrained by `B extends boolean | undefined` right? and then `B` is the type of parameter `b` as in `b?: B`, so when `b` is not passed in, it is `undefined`, then the return type `B extends boolean ? boolean : string` should become `undefined extends boolean ? boolean : string` no?

Comment: hey thank you so much for the code! yea it works! it would be great if you could write up an answer to explain how you arrived at that. Also I do feel like sometimes when working with generics, somewhere along the way I tend to lose binding information... I couldn't pinpoint where exactly it lose it but would love to know if you have any other resources that I can learn more about this limitation/behavior of generic types?

Comment: also @jcalz do you happen to know why in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71117917/7624223, we have to put generic type param `T`  into a tuple as in `type RetType<T> = [T] extends [Callback] ? void : Promise<Result[]>;` to make it work?

Comment: Presumably so that it's not [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) but at this point we're way out of scope

Comment: @jcalz thanks. could you write up an answer for this question though?

Comment: sure when I get a chance

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing has little to do with conditional types.  It's primarily that when a function parameter is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) and you decide not to pass an argument when you call the function, this missing argument *does not* serve as an inference site from which to infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  For example:

```
function bar<T extends true | undefined>(x?: T): void { }
bar(true) // bar<true>()
bar(undefined) // bar<undefined>()
bar(); // bar<true | undefined>();
```

Here `x` is an optional property of type `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `true | undefined`.  If you pass in an explicit value of type `true`, the compiler will infer `true` for `T`.  If you pass in an explicit value of type `undefined`, the compiler will infer `undefined` for `T`.  But when you don't pass in any value whatsoever, the compiler does not infer `T` from this at all. The implicit `undefined` does not participate in type inference.  And so type inference of `T` fails, and the compiler falls back to its constraint, `true | undefined`.

---

One way this can be fixed is for you to specify a [type parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for `T`.  When inference fails, the compiler will fall back to the default instead of the constraint:

```
function bar<T extends true | undefined = undefined>(x?: T): void { }
bar(true) // bar<true>()
bar(undefined) // bar<undefined>()
bar(); // bar<undefined>()
```

Since `T` defaults to `undefined`, the situation for `bar()` changes so that `T` is `undefined`, while the other cases are unchanged.

For your example code, this would look like:

```
function foo<
    A extends (B extends boolean ? boolean : string),
    B extends boolean | undefined = undefined
>(a: A, b?: B): B extends boolean ? boolean : string {
    return a
}

const aa = foo(true, true) // boolean
// function foo<true, true>(a: true, b?: true | undefined): boolean
const aa2 = foo('sdf') // string
// function foo<"sdf", undefined>(a: "sdf", b?: undefined): string
```

as desired.

---

Another approach is to try to simulate [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) more closely by having your function take a rest parameter whose type is a union of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), like this:

```
function foo<T extends [a: boolean, b: boolean] | [a: string]>(...args: T): T[0] {
    return args[0];
}

const aa = foo(true, true) // true
const aa2 = foo('sdf') // "sdf"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgkikAzAV2HgBcMB7YU22gHkOPYCEkIAPKiYABMoSAEZMANhBAMAPkgqCIJDMAiCANG3ZEAgtz4DhSABRde-ISPG0pMpAH4xk6QwBcSKFUzAsASm0kAD4TEA9dDTEHDw4-GINLYxs7Bidk1yQPLx8cAh1iNAgqMjQGEECAX3xA+HovJBAQJABeRloTbzIISM6IPyQAegHnW1dAodIKajoGEiZmXp60LpCwpEWoj16keUVlVXU4kZSauqoGkAAmFraTAHIoQRI7-onAGXJPb1UceXSZceG5EoNHobWYfzkCiE+zUmiQACJHiR4asPIinvDIqJoscMrtoSpYUdst8drj-vgqvhQJBYAhkAARCBgWh4QJA6ag0QgNDMAAqCSMIm2+KUhPUIR4OL5RwAbrQMII8EgquxuWgOss+oNhuqFlqQgE1TyTHtxYJXrqecwzQdBIbAuqTH4ANw6sTWkVQsV2w0uynVangaBwRBIJks655YgckEMPUCixC9Zasm22E3dMSkxSjwyjzyxXK1XEJ29S0e3m9B3GjVZi3uvX1mulk2uxvW5vOgPVGkh+moNQAMQwPDZ7KmcbBgXY+iTVlM5kMC4hjnJ7k+OT8WnyRCXiWsLnsoph6kzBLtgVRSAimyQsXi86SR9S68ym9J0fyhWKpQalWqdhamAepGhuOZ2g2ctGxfAFJmBGYwSgg1Qi2LUsRxL16yOCFThA85GmuVoIPuJEXndElfDg2NEIg5h0WRSIuzWBjMTvbCsi+KieyDWlQ2QPkAHdaBHMcCAnBDQToxNl2MABtNYISxDwIQAXTJBTOJyVSQgAOn0nksCgPMjj5OSAAZ1K-HQfxKMo0CMizVP9dgqSAs4LnAphNS6JYugrXo8NAq4vPaB4nnIiZWMDCogA)

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer!  a follow-up question about this example `function bar<T extends true | undefined = undefined>(x?: T): void { }`I wanted the return type to be `T`, so I rewrote this to `function bar<T extends true | undefined = undefined>(x?: T): T { return x}` but it is complaining that `Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T` so I had to rewrite it using type assertion `function bar<T extends true | undefined = undefined>(x?: T): T { return x as true & undefined}`, are there any other ways to work around this?

Comment: also do you might know why we had to add that type assertion `true & undefined` for the return statement?